# No aparece la carpeta de Diagrama de Base de Datos? Por que?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Eh estado buscando si por usurio de logeo de la base de datoos, propiedades ya sea roles de servidor o de basede datos y nada... tambien busque por visual studio ya que de ahi tambien veo lo que pongo en la base de datos y naa no puedo diagramar las entidades que eh programado en el visual studio.

Alguna sugerencia?¿

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya verificaste que usuario es el propietario????

Comment: si esta como el usuario de autuentificacion de windows pero es por que estoy en ese acceso de sesion